# Build up array of items clicked in a select list and assign values to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already have the functionality to build up the array, but I don't know how to assign the values in the array to another list

```
var subjectAreas = [];

$("#subjectlist")
     .change(function () {
            $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                $('#overview').append("<tr id='" + this.value + "'><td>" + 
                $(this).text() + "</td><td id=" + this.value + ">" "</td> 
                </tr>");
                subjectAreas.push(this.value);    

                //below is the part I don't understand
                $("#SubjectAreasOfProgramme")
                .val(subjectAreas.values.arguments);
            });
     })
.trigger("change");

// below has the id: SubjectAreasOfProgramme and the behind variable is of type List
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SubjectAreasOfProgramme" />
```

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_.

Comment: If I console log $("#SubjectAreasOfProgramme").val(), It only contains the last item clicked

Comment: Will you please clarify more your question So I can get better idea?, You want all selected value from select list to hidden field. Am I Right? @Ryn9011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert array to string and assign the latest values to the hidden input, you might have forgot to give the id to the hidden input. You can test the following snippet by selecting option, entering text and clicking on the button:

```js
var subjectAreas = [];

$("#subjectlist")
  .change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      $('#overview').append("<tr id='" + this.value + "'><td>" +
        $(this).text() + "</td><td id=" + this.value + ">" + "</td>  </tr>");
      subjectAreas.push(this.value);
      $("#SubjectAreasOfProgramme").val(JSON.stringify(subjectAreas));
    });
  })
  .trigger("change");

function logValue() {
  console.log($("#SubjectAreasOfProgramme").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SubjectAreasOfProgramme" id="SubjectAreasOfProgramme" />
<select multiple style="width: 50px;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
<input id="subjectlist" />
<button onclick="logValue();">get SubjectAreasOfProgramme value</button>
<table id="overview">
</table>
```